# Replace org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, feign, openfeign

When I upgrade `implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:2.2.2.RELEASE'` to latest version `implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:3.1.1'`

I get error for this imported class:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient;

@Bean
  public Client client(
      HttpClientConnectionManager httpClientConnectionManager,
      CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory lbClientFactory,
      SpringClientFactory clientFactory) {

    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(httpClientConnectionManager)
        .build();
    ApacheHttpClient delegate = new ApacheHttpClient(closeableHttpClient);
    return new LoadBalancerFeignClient(delegate, lbClientFactory, clientFactory);
  }
```

Do you know how I have to replace them in order to use the latest version?

Comment: The same problem was reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65884281/migrate-feign-load-balancer-implementation-to-compatible-with-spring-cloud-2020. Check if it fixes.

Comment: I check it but it's not solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

ribbon was excluded from that spring boot version, you should now use loadbalancer instead. Check this class `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.FeignLoadBalancerAutoConfiguration`, from my POV, you just need to remove all your ribbon dependencies from the code and that's it.

Comment: How I need to update the above code?

Comment: Just remove the bean and Spring should inject another Client-type bean based on loadbalancer implementation.